# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable in sorting algorithm

Tags: python

I am creating a program in Python which is designed to organise a list, I have been using an insertion sort method, however when I execute the program, after I have input the list top organise, I am returned with the error `"TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable"`
My code is below:

```
def listsort(x):
    for i in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1 
        while i>=0:
            if value < list[i]: 
                list[i+1] = list[i] 
                list[i] = value 
                i = i - 1 
            else:
                break
```

Please help me understand where I have gone wrong here people, it's frying my brain....

Comment: Your input argument is `x`,  but inside a function body you are using `list` (which is a built-in function name).

Comment: Also where does this `index` come from?

Answer (score 1):

`list()` is a python function.

You can't index functions.

Considering using a different variable name. (like `x` since that seems to be the list you are trying to sort)

It's worth noting that `sort()` and `sorted()` are also functions that you may use, but learning sorting methods is good practice.